# Email a dominios externos

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Necesito ayuda para enviar un correo con diseño html en *php mailer*, el caso es que mando mi el correo destinatario a un servidor externo (no a gmail, ni a hotmail, etc), al enviarlo, todo el documento html se desfasa y no llega como deberia, en el caso de gmail y hotmail llega super bien, no se si es problema del servidor de correos destinatario o estoy haciendo algo mal.

Anexo el código:

```
<html>
 <p>$mail = new PHPMailer;   // se crea el objeto mail</p>
  <p>  $mail->isSMTP(); /// se activa smtp</p>
    <p>$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';</p>
    <p>$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;</p>
    <p>$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';</p>
    <p>$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; /// servidor de correo de salida</p>
    <p>$mail->SMTPAuth = true; /// validar authentication</p>
    <p>mail->Username = 'correodeenvio@gmail.com'; /// correo de salida</p>
    <p>$mail->Password = 'XXXXXXX'; //Contraseña</p>
    <p>$mail->Port = 25; ///salida del puerto</p>
    <p>$mail->setFrom('correodeenvio@gmail.com', 'Fes');   //// correo de salida</p>
    <p>$mail->addAddress('correodestino@fes.com.mx', 'Pedido'); /// correo a ventas</p>
    <p>$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML</p>
    <p>$mail->Subject = 'Pedido tienda Online'; // Asunto</p>
    $mail->Body  = "<html>Aqui va todo el diseño</p>
    </html>";
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo ocupo también PHPMailer pero el envió SMTP que ocupo es el de default del servidor donde tengo instalado esto, tal ves te pueda servir como lo hago.

```
    $asunto = "Cotización de " . $sucursal;
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
    $mail->SetFrom($correo, $empresa);
    $address = $correo_cliente;// Aqui va el correo del cliente "N"
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $nombre_cliente);
    $mail->addCC($correo_empresa_gerencia);//copia aun correo especifico
    //Por si decido mandar copia a varios correos
    foreach ($mailres as $key => $value) {
        $mail->addCC($value);
        echo $value;
    }
    $mail->addCC($correo);
    $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($asunto);
    $mail->MsgHTML(utf8_decode($email)); //Aqui mando el HTML del correo.
    $mail->AddAttachment($namecotizacion); // Aqui adjunto la cotizacion.
    if ($mail->Send()) {
        $msjEnvio = "El mensaje se envio con exito";
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, al final tuve que contactar al usuario encargado  del servidor para que me otorgara permisos

Answer (score 1):

Que yo sepa debe ir de esta manera.

```
$html = "<html>
          <p>Todo el codigo html que quieras</p>
        </html>";
$mail = new PHPMailer;   // se crea el objeto mail
$mail->isSMTP(); /// se activa smtp
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; /// servidor de correo de salida
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; /// validar authentication
mail->Username = 'correodeenvio@gmail.com'; /// correo de salida
$mail->Password = 'XXXXXXX'; //Contraseña
$mail->Port = 25; ///salida del puerto
$mail->setFrom('correodeenvio@gmail.com', 'Fes');   //// correo de salida
$mail->addAddress('correodestino@fes.com.mx', 'Pedido'); /// correo a ventas
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Pedido tienda Online'; // Asunto
$mail->Body  = $html;
```

Comment: De echo seria lo mismo, solo se declara una variable extra "$html", a lo que me refiero es que el correo destinatario tiene una dirección de correo de un servidor externo @fest.com.mx, no se si el servidor de correo externo tenga algo que ver al no aceptar estilos en los mensajes de entrada, puesto que a los de hotmail y gmail llega a la perfeccion y se ve bien